# Unable to Update column with new value using pandas getting settingwithcopywarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to update a existent column in pandas dataframe with. I am converting a string column to timestamp using

```
pd.to_datetime(ShortCSV['Date TIme']
```

then I want to update the same column ShortCSV['Date TIme'] so I do

```
ShortCSV['Date TIme'] = pd.to_datetime(ShortCSV['Date TIme'])
```

but I get the settingwithcopywarning

> ```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> ```

I kind of get the reason we need to use the .loc but in my case I dont have a condition to meet in order to update the column. so How can I do this? any idea?

Let me know your comments please

Thanks

Comment: `ShortCSV` is a view into another dataframe.  Question 1: Do you want to change `ShortCSV` without changing the other dataframe from which it was derived?  If yes, then do this first... `ShortCSV = ShortCSV.copy()`  Then do what you did.

Comment: I actually want to replace ShortCSV['Date Time'] with the new value timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following to see if you still get the warning?

```
ShortCSV = ShortCSV.copy()
ShortCSV['Date TIme'] = pd.to_datetime(ShortCSV['Date TIme'])
```

Comment: Yes this works as @piRSquared said as well but If I understand correctly doing this will not change the ShortCSV? I can see that it did update the values in ShortCSV.

Comment: It will because your old ShortCSV no longer exists. Any reference to ShortCSV going forward will reference your new copy.